# What differences do I need to know choosing between ext4 and NTFS (Performance etc)

Tags: filesystem, performance, ntfs, ext4

I understand that ext4 if faster than NTFS. But whats the speed difference if its like < 20MB/s, perhaps its better to use NTFS for convinence? What are the other implications of this apart from performance?

Comment: ext4 is faster than NTFS on Linux but it might not be true on Windows

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very comprehensive [Comparison of file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems).

NTFS has both read and write access now in Linux through NTFS-3G, and you can use [third-party programs](https://superuser.com/questions/311934/how-to-read-ext2-from-windows-7-64-bit) to gain access to an EXT2/3/4 filesystem from within a Windows operating system.

Comment: Yes but what about the performance part?

Answer (score 2):

What I do on my 500g drive is 200 Gig is ext4 300 Gig is Ntfs so what i want to share with my Windows Systems are on the 300 Gig partition. Then I just share the folders that i want the Windows Systems to see over the network. Besides its a good ideal to have a Storage Partition in case if you need to reformat and your data you wanna keep is already backed up. As long as the drive its self doesn't die your good.

Comment: I have a 300GB drive w/ quad-boot 50GB Windows7, 20GB Kubuntu11.04 (primary boot OS 99.9% of the times), 15GB Ubuntu11.04 & 15GB Fedora6, 200GB NTFS storage drive, 130MB boot partition and 4GB swap partition. OS installations w/ individual programs are kept for each respective OS on the smaller partitions, while all downloads, music, videos and general storage goes directly on the 200GB drive w/ shared access to all. This way whenever I need to reinstall an OS it is very simple to just wipe a single partition and install onto it(which happens more of often than usual w/ a quad-boot setup).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's relative, and I also think the best way it's to run some small tests on your own system.

I will always recommend to use a native file system, but if you plan to share the file system, then performance it's on second place.